# Create an observable wrapper for a non thread safe class

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a class,

```
public class Test
{
  public int Calc();
}
```

which requires all calls to Calc to be performed on the same thread as the one on which Test was created. I need to create Test once (expensive operation) and call Calc multiple times.

I'd like to have a wrapper that will let me call Calc asynchronousely:

```
public class TestWrapper
{
  private Test _test;
  public IObservable<int> Calc();
}
```

One way to do it would be to create a BackgroundWorker or a Thread and use it as a guarantee that all operations on Test are on the same thread. For simplicity, we can assume that all calls to Calc() will be executed sequentially, so no need to worry about queueing.

Is there a more elegant RX way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's possible for `Test` to be created when `TestWrapper` is created then this class seems to meet your requirements:

```
public class TestWrapper
{
    public TestWrapper(Func<Test> factory)
    {
        _scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
        _test = Observable.Start(factory, _scheduler).First();
    }

    private readonly EventLoopScheduler _scheduler;
    private readonly Test _test;

    public IObservable<int> Calc()
    {
        return Observable.Start(() => _test.Calc(), _scheduler);
    }
}
```

It is used like so:

```
var testWrapper = new TestWrapper(() => new Test());
testWrapper.Calc().Subscribe(x => { });
```

I've tested it and it creates `Test` on the same thread that `Calc` is executed on. The subscription, on the other hand, is handled on the same thread as the `testWrapper` itself was created on (i.e. the calling thread).

Answer (score 3):

So from comments and re-reading your question I gather you want to repeatedly call Calc() on a constant thread and have the return results available as an `IObservable<Int>()`?

In this case, I'd use `Observable.Create` to wrap the `Test` class, and the `EventLoopScheduler` to ensure the invocations to Calc are on a single thread.

```
public class TestWrapper
{
  private Test _test;
  public IObservable<int> Calc()
  {
    return Observable.Create(obsvr =>
    {
        var fixedThreadsched = new EventLoopScheduler();
        var disp = new BooleanDisposable();
        while (!disp.IsDisposed)
        {
            fixedThreadsched.Schedule(() => obsvr.OnNext(_test.Calc()));
        }

        return disp;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, EventLoopScheduler is a key to marshaling calls to the same thread. Still, this answer does not explain how to switch from TestWrapper.Calc which will be executed on UI thread to test.Calc...

Comment: @Sergey - Updated based on your comments

Comment: This is closer... The piece missing is that you don't create _test (which should be done on the EventLoopScheduler). Hmm... Hard to decide - you were the first with EventLoopScheduler but @enigmativity provided the correct answer. Thank you guys you both rock!

Comment: Fair enough, but the above should give clear indication of how to do that

Answer (score 0):

use the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) class when creating your instance of `Test`:

```
var MyTEST = new ThreadLocal<Test>();
```

then you can use `MyTEST.Value.Calc ()` for any calls...

Another option is to use put `[ThreadStatic]` on the Test member of the wrapper class...
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx

Depending on whether you need more than one instance of `Test` you could make it a [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) .